# Find Common data across multiple databases

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm a newbie to MySQL and I've been given a challenging assignment by my boss.

The assignment is, build a stored procedure that queries different tables in different databases and finds common data (not including ID's, just varchar columns) between the tables.  I've found solutions online but they don't fit my scenario because of this one issue:

Not all of the columns have the same name.  Sometimes the column is called, 'accnt_no', other times, 'account_number', or 'accnt_nmbr'.  And this is just one example of discrepancies in a column name.  There are **many** examples where the column names don't match.

I build a statement to query the schema tables like this:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA AS DBNAME, TABLE_NAME AS TNAME, COLUMN_NAME AS CNAME
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('db1','db2','db3','db4','db5')
AND TABLE_NAME IN ('table_1','table_2','table_3','table_4','table_5','table_6','table_7','table_8','table_9','table_10','table_11','table_12','table_13','table_14','table_15','table_16')
AND DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'
ORDER by 1, 2, 3;
```

in hopes that, I could iterate the results and build some dynamic queries like:

select CNAME from DBNAME.TNAME WHERE...(obviously, this syntax doesn't work).  But don't know the syntax for how to build out the queries from this resultset, except to say that it will probably require nested looping.  I just started at this company a month ago so I'm not really in a position to lecture anyone about their naming conventions.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Yep, typical noob assignment

Comment: Can we assume that even though the column naming are different, there are still a few identical characteristics on them? for example `accnt_no`, `account_number` and `accnt_nmbr` have the first 3 characters similarities of `acc` at the beginning and two characters of `_n` in the middle.

Comment: Yes.  There is **some** similarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way that I can think of is using [prepared statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html).

First, create the MySQL query from `information_schema.columns`:

```
SET @sql := NULL;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
              CONCAT("SELECT ",COLUMN_NAME," FROM ",TABLE_SCHEMA,".",TABLE_NAME)
                    SEPARATOR " UNION ALL ") 
       INTO @sql
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
/*WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('db1','db2','db3','db4','db5')*/
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ('table1','table2','table3','table4')
AND DATA_TYPE = 'varchar'
AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE "acc%"
AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE "%_n%";
```

If you execute `SELECT @sql;` after executing the query above, you'll get result like this:

```
SELECT acc_no FROM db_366220190.table1 UNION ALL 
SELECT account_no FROM db_366220190.table2 UNION ALL 
SELECT acct_number FROM db_366220190.table3 UNION ALL 
SELECT acc_num FROM db_366220190.table4
```

Then right after, you just have to prepare the statement, execute then deallocate with the following command:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Here's a demo fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c4b26ba2f46430ab2c196b30aedc38f

Comment: Thanks, @FaNo_FN.  This got me very far.